# How to deal with SEHException in Visual c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-c++

I have written code about inpaint and part of the code as bellow. 
The software is Visual C++ 2010 and the library is OpenCV2.4.7.

included library:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <opencv/cvaux.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
```

part of the code regarding to inpaint

```
        IplImage *modified = cvLoadImage("D:\\save\\shutter1.bmp",0);
        IplImage *original = cvLoadImage("D:\\save\\shutter0.bmp",0);
        IplImage *imageProcess = cvCreateImage(cvSize(this->width,this->height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);

        cv::Mat src1 = cv::imread("D:\\save\\shutter0.bmp");

        cvAbsDiff(original,modified,imageProcess);
        cvThreshold(imageProcess,imageProcess,1,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        IplConvKernel *pKernel = NULL;
        pKernel = cvCreateStructuringElementEx(5, 5, 2, 2, CV_SHAPE_RECT, NULL);
        cvDilate(imageProcess, imageProcess, pKernel, 3);
        cvErode(imageProcess, imageProcess, pKernel, 3);

        cvSaveImage("D:\\save\\Result.bmp",imageProcess);
        cv::Mat mask = cv::imread("D:\\save\\Result.bmp");
        cv::Mat dst1;
        inpaint(src1, mask, dst1, 1,cv::INPAINT_TELEA);
        imshow("image", dst1);

        cvShowImage("modified", modified );
        cvShowImage("original", original );
        cvShowImage("imageProcess", imageProcess );
        cvWaitKey(1);
        cvReleaseImage(&original);
        cvReleaseImage(&modified);
        cvReleaseImage(&imageProcess);
```

This code can pass the compiler. However, when I ran this code, there will generate a window says "**System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException**". And this code stopped at the line`imshow("image", dst1);`. I think that the problem may results from the function of `inpaint()`. I have read plenty of articles about SEHException, but I still don't know how to handle this problem. I also don't know why does this code generate this problem?

Comment: please stop using the deprecated c-api, they moved to a c++ one in 2010 already. (especially, *mixing* c and c++ calls is the straight road to desaster)

Comment: Can you run this code in the debugger and find out which line is giving you the exception?

Comment: I can't totally realize the "c-api". What is c-api? Which part in this code is used in c-api? The initial environment I chose was C++.

Comment: @Jaywalker when I deleted these three lines `cv::Mat dst1;inpaint(src1, mask, dst1, 1,cv::INPAINT_TELEA);imshow("image", dst1);` the code would be OK. the first line`cv::Mat dst1;`and the third line`imshow("image", dst1);` may not have any problem.

Comment: I used try and catch to determine the type of Exception. I obtained the message as bellow.
**External component has thrown an exception**

Comment: usage of IplImages, cv* functions is deprecated. use cv::Mat and cv::functions instead, *please*.

Comment: @berak After reading your comment and searching on the Internet, I know what you mention. Maybe, I should adopt your method when I write the code in the future. Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for more website and using try and catch to find the exception, I know the reason of this SEHException results from the wrong parameter in function inpaint(). I modified the code and it can run correctly. The revised code as follow.

```
    cvSaveImage("D:\\save\\Result.bmp",imageProcess);
    cv::Mat src1 = cv::imread("D:\\save\\shutter0.bmp");
    cv::Mat img,mask;
    img = cv::imread("D:\\save\\Result.bmp",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    mask=cv::Mat::zeros(this->width, this->height, CV_8UC1);
    mask=img;
    cv::Mat dst1; 
    cv::imshow("mask",mask);
    inpaint(src1, mask, dst1, 1,cv::INPAINT_NS);
    cvWaitKey(1000);
    cv::imshow("inpainted", dst1);
```